# How to Reduce the padding of the Google Maps Places API v3 InfoWindow

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I tried to get the id of the object with FireBug, but no success.

I've also played around with the InfoBox code from google Maps, but was too complex, for the little thing I need, which is just to reduce the padding of the infowindow.

Comment: [Link to live code](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete.html) @andresf

Just search for something, and the infoWindow will open.

Answer (score -2):

Line 17 of the page you linked to shows how the infowindow content is constructed:

```
infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' + address);
```

You'll need to set the padding for the  either inline (e.g., `style="padding: 0px;"`) or through a CSS class (e.g., `class="myInfoWindow"`) and then set the CSS properties in your head or a separate CSS file.

So using the former, you would change the line to:

```
infowindow.setContent('<div style="padding: 0px;"><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' + address);
```

Comment: Hi Andres, I tried what you proposed, but it didn't work. There is a superior Div, that controls the padding of the InfoWindow, and that's automatically done by Google. If I could just know the ID of that Div, I could apply a class like you suggested, but can't manage to get it via FireBug. @andresf

Comment: I don't think any padding is explicitly set by the Maps API on that DIV.  One option would be to use jQuery to select the parent DIV(s) and apply formatting on the fly...you could set a DIV id, and then use the id to reference the child div when the content is shown in the infowindow (via an event listener).

Comment: I don't really understand how? I wanted for all infoWindows, shouldn't be easier with a CSS class?

Comment: The interior div is absolutely sized and positioned with inline CSS. Not sure of any way to change that other than overriding it with javascript