# Get Google Map Places ID from existing markers

Tags: google-maps

Chasing my tail trying to find a good example of how to populate the infowindow with place details.

My scenario is :

- I already have markers on my map from KML layers
- when I click on the markers only the title appears
- I want the places details populated in the infowindow
- all the examples I find online are of finding place id by creating new markers not from existing markers on the page

I found a couple examples, but none seem to work for me:

[Google Maps Places api, how do I get the standard infowindow content from a marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10643388/google-maps-places-api-how-do-i-get-the-standard-infowindow-content-from-a-mark)
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-placeid-finder

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-details

Here is a link to my code, I hope someone can walk me through it, I am lost...

https://github.com/smartcookiemedia/google-maps-script/blob/master/google-maps.js

Answer (score 1):

For instance, you can look for place details when a marker is clicked.

To do that

1. You should set suppressInfoWindows to true

   ```
   var layer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(baseurl + kml[id].url, {
       preserveViewport: true,
       suppressInfoWindows: true
   });
   ```
2. add click listener to the layer

   ```
   layer.addListener('click', function(kmlEvent) {

       var request = {
          location: kmlEvent.latLng,
          radius: '10',
          name: kmlEvent.featureData.name
       };

       service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
   });
   ```
3. and make the callback function looking like this

   ```
   function callback(results, status) {
       if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
           var place = results[0];
           infowindow.setContent(place.name + ' ' + place.place_id);
           infowindow.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
           infowindow.open(map);
       }
   }
   ```

The result will look like this

[image]

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH for your help...I would have never figured that out by myself.  Note, looking up by name does not give you the placeDetail response, I had to do another request based on place_id.  I didn't know another way...its a little wee sluggish because of the two requests, do you know a better mouse trap? Updated code here:

https://github.com/smartcookiemedia/google-maps-script/blob/master/google-maps.js

Thanks again!

Comment: No. Only that you can store place ids somewhere (in the kml files?). See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#placeid